# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: html, python, web

Estoy intentando hacer un programa web, pero al momento que quiero arrojar el mensaje me sale el siguiente error:

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
def name_com(nombre):
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("C:\\Users\\ESantana\\Documents\\PruebaHMTL"))
    template = env.get_template("index.html")
    apellidos="Santana Barcenas"
    completo =nombre+apellidos
    print(completo)
    html, = template.render(completo)
    print(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nombre='Edwin '
    name_com(nombre)
```

& en mi HTML asi estoy reciviendo la cadena

```
<p {{completo}} </p>
```

Comment: Esta coma tendria que estar ahi?  html, = template.render(completo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al método `render` le pasas un argumento posicional (la cadena `completo`) cuando espera un diccionario.

De la [documentación de Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Template.render):

> This method accepts the same arguments as the dict constructor: A dict, a dict subclass or some keyword arguments.

Es decir, este método acepta los mismos argumentos que el constructor de `dict`, una instancia de `dict` o de una subclase de esta o bien una suerte de argumentos de tipo `keyword`.

O le pasas argumentos por nombre:

```
html = template.render(completo=completo)
```

O le pasas un diccionario directamente:

```
html = template.render({"completo": completo})
```

La clave en el diccionario o el nombre del argumento corresponde al usado en el template.

> **Nota:** tal y como  comentaba @alanfcn la coma en `html, =` causará un **ValueError** al intentar desempaquetar dos valores del retorno del método `render`, que solo retorna el template renderizado como una cadena unicode.